# How to add API version to Apiary Mock Server

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

Is there any way to add API version to Apiary Mock Server?

Ex.: http://private-XXXXX-apiname.apiary-mock.com/`v1`/mocks/1?school_id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when declaring `HOST`, you can append suffix to it and that is then propagated as prefix to all resources:

`FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://api.example.tld/v1/`

Comment: No problem! glad to be able to help.

Comment: Does it mean for 2 versions of an API (for backward compatibility) , one need to keep two .apib files?