# What is the purpose of the Host: parameter in Apiary?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

What is the purpose of the `Host:` parameter in Apiary. For example:

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://polls.apiblueprint.org/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HOST` header states what is the final intended deployment of your API.

It's used on Apiary as an upstream location for debugging proxy, and appears in code snippets as a location for requests.

You can also add suffixes that are then propagated to all resources if you are not running on root or [want to version through URI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30245487/123558).

Mock and proxy server also emulate the schema you've specified (`http` vs. `https`).

Resources:

- [HOST in specification](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#metadata-section)
- [How it works](https://apiary.io/how-it-works) (see traffic inspector section)
- [What's new blogpost](http://blog.apiary.io/2012/05/21/to-our-wonderful-beta-testers/) (see Pass-Through Proxy section)

Comment: Thanks. I had to dig a bit deeper to find the information I was looking for. The link to the specification does not explain the purpose of the `Host` parameter, but that it is only a metadata. However thanks to the _Traffic Inspector_ section [here](https://apiary.io/how-it-works) as well as [this](http://blog.apiary.io/2012/05/21/to-our-wonderful-beta-testers/) blog post and the Settings section of the app, now it is all clear.

Comment: No problem—Apiary is now doing a lot of groundwork to make documentation and its experience a lot better :) Updated the answer with links.

Comment: Spent half an hour mucking with your product. Extremely poor documentation and nothing simple. There are other services out there where you can do mocks in under 5 minutes without even reading any documentation or even worse resorting to Stackoverflow to get even the most basic mock up and running. Can't recommend this service at all.

Comment: @AndroidDev Purpose of Apiary goes well beyond creating mock services, which is why it's setup is a bit more complicated. We are working on improving the docs (see [new dev portal](https://docs.apiary.io)) and it will spill into FTUE as well.